# See who downvoted your answer

Tags: support

I answered a question regarding pistons in minecraft and how to control them individually. What I didn't see was that he later commented that they were vertical, however, he never edited the question.

Long story short I answered the question (and put a lot of effort into the answer) and then the asker commented that it was vertical, not horizontal. So I posted a comment that said To wait one moment (to avoid downvotes). However, someone completely ignored that comment and downvoted anyway without leaving a comment as they should have and I lost 2 rep points.

I know it was only two rep points but still.

So my question is, how can I notify the person to re-vote my answer?

Comment: Voting is 100% anonymous so unless the person posted as to why they down voted you there is no way to notify them. But fret not, if you have a good answer you will earn more up votes and be able to ignore that down vote in any case :)

Comment: There is something called 'revenge downvoting'. I am not sayin you are, but I know people who are vengeful.. extremely.. they'd go and downvote every question and answer that you've ever written if they ever knew it was you who downvoted them just because... So no.. I am HIGHLY against revealing names of voters.

Comment: I didnt do that. I only asked the question because I just wanted to know if I could notify the person. I think it would be nice if you would get notified if a question or answer that you voted on gets edited. :)

Comment: You can always delete your answer if you want the rep back, just remember you'll lose any rep from upvotes too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to "notify" people is to leave a comment stating that you have corrected whatever problem there was with your post. You can't directly notify downvoters unless they leave a comment saying "hey, fix X", and if they do, just leave a comment reply for them clarifying that you've corrected the issue.

Comment: Everyone can also see revisions on a post, so leaving a comment isn't strictly necessary unless the downvoter(s) commented in the first place.

Comment: @AnnaLear true, but most people don't read those. In fact most probably skip comments. The important thing is that your answer is correct as soon as possible.

Comment: Well I accepted your answer, but sadly they didn't leave a comment. however, as James said "if you have a good answer you will earn more up votes". That is exactly what happened